# Verificar a versão do aplicativo na Google play

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

Existe algum Web Service que retorna a versão do meu aplicativo? Porque por exemplo eu tenho a versão 1.2 (mais atual) e quando o usuário abrir e por exemplo for a versão 1.1 não deixar ele executar o aplicativo enquanto não atualizar. Eu poderia fazer uma Api minha que me retornasse a versão e cada vez que eu atualizasse eu teria que ir na Api e mudar também. Desde já agradeço

Comment: Vlw. Creio que vou precisar fazer isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jeito mais prático é você criar uma API que você seta a ultima versão do seu app, dentro do app você faz a verificação se a resposta da api é menor ou igual a versão atual, assim bloqueando o usuário a dar continuidade no app (pode direcionar ele ao link do seu app na loja pra ele atualizar).